# What is the effect of putting an @ after a traits name?

Tags: python, traits, enthought

I stumbled upon [this example](https://github.com/enthought/traitsui/blob/master/examples/demo/Advanced/List_editor_notebook_selection_demo.py) for python traits ListEditor:

Can someone tell me why there is an "@" behind 'people' in the View definition(line 75)?

I couldn't find anything in the traits doc

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is a little-used, undocumented shortcut for [`style='custom'`](https://github.com/enthought/traitsui/blob/master/traitsui/view_element.py#L181). Consider it a bad idea that should not be emulated and will be removed from the examples shortly.